Creating layer group through the API gives unexpected error about 'Layer group within a workspace … can not contain resources from other workspace …'
I have multiple workspaces with identical structure for presenting different, but structurally identical data sets.
In all I have feature layers "a" and "b", both from PostGIS tables.
When I update data in a workspace (using Geoserver Rest Python library) I want to recreate a layergroup containing both "a" and "b".
Uploading new data using my code works for the first data set I import into its workspace. When I try a second, it apparently complains that I illegally want to use the layers from the earlier-created workspace:
'Layer group within a workspace … can not contain resources from other workspace …'
From a quick reading of the geoserver-rest code, this happens inside the final call to create the layer group itself.
Why doesn’t GeoServer take the identically named layers from the workspace specified as the destination for the new layer group? How can I avoid this behaviour?
I have already tried using member layer names of ws:a and ws:b and ws,a and ws,b but get errors about those being invalid:
Layer: wsname:a is not a valid layer in the GeoServer instance

Try setting it up in the GUI and then looking at the rest representation of the layergroup to see what is different from your one
